# PHP - preg_match()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Alright, so I want the user to be able to enter every character from A-Z and every number from 0-9, but I don't want them entering "special characters".

Code:

```
if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/", $user_name)) {
    #Stuff
}
```

How is it possible for it to check all of the characters given, and then check if those were matched? I've tried `preg_match_all()`, but I didn't honestly understand much of it.

Like if a user entered "FaiL65Mal", I want it to allow it and move on. But if they enter "Fail{]^7(,", I want it to appear with an error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need a quantifier in your regex:

Zero or more characters `*`:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/
```

One or more characters `+`:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

Your regex as is will only match a string with exactly one character that is either a letter or number. You want one of the above options for zero or more or one or more, depending on if you want to allow or reject the empty string.

Comment: Thank you! I wish they explained this in the hour+ of tutorials on YouTube I had watched.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression needs to be changed to

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8}$/
```

For usernames between 1 and 8 characters. Just adjust the 8 to the appropriate number and perhaps the 1.

*Currently your expression matches one character*

Comment: I don't think the goal was to limit the user name to 8 characters.

Comment: I just used 8 as an example. Usually people have upper limits on usernames (as they are stored in databases for example). That is why I put the comment that you can adjust those values.

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mid that `preg_match()` and other `preg_*()` functions aren't reliable because they return either `0` or `false` on fail, so a simple if won't throw on error.

Consider using [T-Regx](https://github.com/T-Regx/T-Regx):

```
if (pattern(('^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8}$')->matches($input)) 
{
    // Matches! :)
}
```