# PHP parse sentence and store information in variables

Tags: php, parsing, artificial-intelligence

In PHP I'm trying to make a natural text recognition system that can recognise what you write in an intelligent way. 
I'd like it to match a sentence with a 'pattern' and store some information, for example if `schedule a {scheduletype} with {person} at {time}` is compared to `Schedule a meeting with Ann at 3pm`, the PHP code will create variables `$scheduletype` with the value meeting, `$person` with Ann and `$time` with 3pm. Is it also possible to make it work if the sentence is written in a different order, for example 'At 3pm shedule a meeting with Ann`?
I've tried looking on Google and Stack Exchange for this but unfortunately haven't found anything.

Here's my current code:

```
$pattern = 'schedule a ([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\/\?_=&;]*) with ([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\/\?_=&;]*) at ([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\/\?_=&;]*)';
$content = 'shedule a meeting with Ann at 3pm';


$match = preg_match($pattern, strtolower($content) , $found);
print_r($match);
```

The problem is that my code doesn't assign anything to `$preg_match`.

Comment: Try using Regex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917120/php-preg-match

Comment: @James Here's my code: `$pattern = 'schedule a ([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\/\?_=&;]*) with ([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\/\?_=&;]*) at ([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\/\?_=&;]*)';
$content = 'shedule a meeting with Ann at 3pm';

$match = preg_match($pattern, strtolower($content) , $found);
print_r($match);`

Comment: You probably need to defined a specific set of `scheduletype`s and `person`s and check for their existence in a given sentence. The `time` should be regex-able.

Comment: @James It's done.

Comment: `$pattern = 'schedule` and `$content = 'shedule` are your problem, at this time...

Comment: IMHO the problem is that your trying to solve a pattern for 1 sentence.  This will work, but how will this help in the general sense of 'recognise what you write in an intelligent way'

Comment: @NigelRen that's why I added 'Is it also possible to make it work if the sentence is written in a different order, for example `At 3pm schedule a meeting with Ann`?' in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sort of named capture group regex:

```
#Schedule a (?<scheduletype>\w+)\swith\s(?<person>\w+)\sat\s(?<time>\w+)#
```

Example:

```
<?php

$regex= '#Schedule a (?<scheduletype>\w+)\swith\s(?<person>\w+)\sat\s(?<time>\w+)#';
preg_match($regex, 'Schedule a meeting with Ann at 3pm', $matches);

echo $matches['scheduletype']."\n";
echo $matches['person']."\n";
echo $matches['time']."\n";
```

Play with the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/6QPRsG/1/

Play with the code here: https://3v4l.org/OBOnY

Comment: I did a little edit so I can write the bits to replace with curly brackets: `$regex = str_replace('{', '(?<', 'schedule a {scheduletype} with {person} at {time}');
$regex = '#'. str_replace('}', '>\w+)', $regex). '#';`

Comment: @delboy1878uk It's so much simpler to write if I'm going to add lots of these

Comment: can you show an example? i have no idea why you would want to string replace the pattern to match